# ASP.NET Core API Securing PDF File Endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have an endpoint on my API that serves PDFs to users, and a web app that displays a link to the endpoint in a simple href to allow the user to click on the link and have the PDF download and display directly in their browser. A sample link to an endpoint would look like:

```
<a href=http://localhost:51660/api/v1/MyAPI/GetPDF?id=94a8ea0b-aec9-4812-839f-a2f7f4d0e122>
```

This works just fine, the problem is this endpoint is difficult to secure as I can't really pass the JWT token in the headers as we would for the other endpoints in the API since it's just a simple link in order to use the native PDF viewer in browsers. I can try storing a cookie from the front end with the JWT token then try to read this from the API, though this feels like a clunky solution to add in cookie authentication and use this for a singular route in the API, when everything else uses JWT bearer authentication but I can't think of any other way around this.

I need to be able to pass the token so that I can verify the user and the organisation they are a part of to ensure they aren't trying to access a file they shouldn't be allowed to view, but I can't really think of a non-clunky way to get around this. Is this something I'll just have to accept?